# Problem erasing files from DVD-RW

Tags: permissions, dvd

I burned a movie in some DVD-RW and now I want to replace it by another movie, i.e, erase the files from the DVD-RW and burn another. I check some suggestions online, and found brasero's the best, but I always got permission issues. I tried to right click on the DVD and, in properties, change the permission, but it doesn't work. The methods I found online for changing permission are to complicated. Anyway, is there a more easy way of doing it?

Have a nice day.

P.S.: This's what happens

http://postimg.org/image/rw1mdb14z/

http://postimg.org/image/3m7jdiub3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the better you can do is to erase the content of the DVD (more or less like formating a disk).

In Brasero you have the option in the tools menu to `Blank` a disk. This will erase all the content from the disk and prepare it to write new data. It's possible that you have closed the DVD and this is why you don't have permissions to write in it.

Also, it can be because you account isn't running Brasero with enough permissions, for this you can try to open Brasero from a terminal with `sudo brasero`.

If you add more information, maybe we can give you a better answer. For example, what is the exact message that appear?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried to put some images of the messages but SE forum requires 10 points reputation for that.. Wonderful!

Comment: You can add a link to the image and also, you can copy the text as it is in the dialogs. Have you tried what I said in my answer?

Comment: Link added. Yes I did, see the pics.

Comment: Can you try to use `dbus-launch brasero` to see if it detects your disc? (found in [this link](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=95848)) If this don't solve it, I don't know why it don't detect your disc and maybe it's better that you test other software like K3B (it's what I normally use).

Comment: It worked with K3B. Thank you for your help!